# AVPlayerView crash in Swift

Tags: swift, avplayer, avplayerview

In my macOS App I have a window with a `AVPlayerView`. When run from Xcode the window opens and the video plays. However, when I export (Archive>Copy App) the app and open it the window with AVPlayerView crashes.

I suspect the issue is that the app is unable to access the video file when the app is exported.

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

class IntroVC: NSViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        avViewConfig()
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var avView: AVPlayerView!
    
    
    func avViewConfig(){
        
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "one", ofType: ".mp4") {
            let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)
            
            let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)
            
            avView.player = player
            avView.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

I added the video file by dragging it directly into the project folder.
[image]

Comment: Add to targets check mark should need enable. Did you try that?

Comment: I've been actually trying with the target selected. On the screenshot I forgot to select the target.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't know what the issue was but removing the `AVPlayerView` from the storyboard and programatically adding one seems to have fixed the issue.

```
class IntroVC: NSViewController{
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        avViewConfig()
        avPlayerView.frame = self.view.frame
        view.addSubview(avPlayerView)
    }
    
    var avPlayerView = AVPlayerView()
    
    func avViewConfig(){
        
        if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "one", ofType: ".mp4") {
            let filePathURL = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filePath)

            let player = AVPlayer(url: filePathURL)

            avPlayerView.player = player
            avPlayerView.player?.play()
        }
    }
}
```